# RGraphviz Hasse Diagram displaying only one lable

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, visualization, r-graphviz

In order to create an Hasse Diagram like the following

[image]

One is using the following libraries

```
library(rPref)
library(Rgraphviz)
```

One is taking a small sample of one's data

```
df <- data[1:10,]
```

Then creating the preferences

```
pref <- low(time) * low(MAPE)
```

And the Better-Than-Graph (BTG)

```
btg <- get_btg(df, pref)
```

In order to display the labels for the nodes containing relevant values, one is creating the labels as following

```
labels <- paste0(df$time, "\n", df$MAPE)
```

However, when one builds the visualization with

```
plot_btg(df, pref, labels)
```

One can only see the first label, instead of the two. Here is what one is seeing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `use_dot=FALSE` solved the problem

```
plot_btg(df, pref, labels, use_dot = FALSE)
```

[image]